# What are these extra bytes in the http basic header?

Tags: authentication, http-headers

When i try to connect to my TPLINK TL-WR841N routers webserver, my browser sends credentials in the following format.

```
Cookie: Authorization=Basic%20YWRtaW46MjEyMzJmMjk3YTU3YTVhNzQzODk0YTBlNGE4MDFmYzM%3D
```

By using sources option in the browser, i figure out that the base64 string is actually the result of the following function i.e.

```
BASE64{username:md5(password)}
```

instead of basic authentication method which should be

```
BASE64(username:password)
```

Here is the snippet

[image]

There are three extra bytes at the start and end of the string i.e. {%20,%3D}.

[image]

What these bytes represents ?

Couldn't found anything relate to it in [RFC-7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just ' ' and '=' characters encoded in HTML.

See here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp